# Firebase setValue() works in simulator but not on device, anyone know why? iOS 10, Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios10, swift3

This code saves to the Firebase database as required in the simulator but the completion handler doesn't get called on the device. Does anyone know why or of a possible fix?

```
var customersRef : FIRDatabaseReference {
            return dbRef.child("customers")
    }


func saveDealData(dealBuilder: DealBuilder, errMsgHandler: ErrMsgHandler?) {
            print("Shown in log in sim and device")
            customersRef.child(u.id!).child("deals").childByAutoId().setValue("true") { error, dbRef in
                    print("Is called for sim but not device")

            }
    }
```

I've tried getting rid of trailing closure and putting inside setValue() as below, but the same happens:

```
  customersRef.child(u.id!).child("deals").childByAutoId().setValue("true", withCompletionBlock:  { error, dbRef in
                    print("Is called in sim but not device")
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour was fixed by casting the Swift string as NSString.

As below:

```
customersRef.child(u.id!).child(("deals" as NSString)).childByAutoId().setValue("true") { error, dbRef in
                print("Is now always called")

        }
```